# How to implement rewrite and redirect using htacees

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have successfully rewrote the following:
OLD: wwww.example.com/company.php
NEW: wwww.example.com/company
 Using this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^company/?$ company.php [NC,L]
```

But when I go to /company.php, it does not automatically redirect me to /company . Why? I tried [r=301,L],  instead of [NC,L], but did not help: How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine On
#externally redirect /company.php to /company
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /company\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /company [L,R]
#internaally redirect /company to /company.php
RewriteRule ^company/?$ company.php [NC,L]
```